# How do I create an HTML document in my code behind and load it into a WPF browser

Tags: c#, html, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a C# WPF application. In my UI I have a `WebBrowser` that is collapsed and will remain collapsed at all times. In my code behind I want to create an HTML document and load this document into the collapsed `WebBrowser`.

The only thing I can think of is writing my HTML as a string and then using `File.Create()` to create file and then using `Browser.Navigate` to navigate to that file.

The problem is though, I don't want to create any temp files on the computer or have to reference any file paths. Is there any way to create some kind of HTML file object in memory and then pass this object to the `WebBrowser` to be loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NavigateToString or NavigateToStream methods of WebBrowser control.

I suggest to you, Use navigateToString method. Just pass html text to method.